# How to add the build files as an asset to a release in Github?

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, semantic-release

I have a project based on Node/npm and use commitlint, husky and semantic-release. Whenever I push to the protected `main` branch I want to create a new release.

In Github I added the following workflow

```
name: Release on push on main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  release-on-push-on-main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: npx semantic-release --branches main
```

which does the job very well. When moving to the releases I see that semantic-release attaches the source code

[image]

Running `npm run build` generates me a `dist` folder containing all the build files. How can enhance my workflow to add the build to the assets?

[image]

Adding the steps

```
  - name: Run build
    run: npm run build

  - name: Archive build
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: build
      path: dist
```

before running the `Release` step seems to work as expected

[image]

but how can I add it as an asset to the release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the semantic-release [github-plugin](https://github.com/semantic-release/github)
using the [configuration file](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#configuration)

The CLI uses some default configuration, and if you need a custom config
you will have to create an entire config from scratch (as far as I know).

Create a file called release.config.js in the root project folder:

```js
// make sure you install @semantic-release/github as dev dependency
module.exports =  {
  "plugins": [
    // additional config...

    ["@semantic-release/github", {
      "assets": [
        {"path": "dist/asset.min.css", "label": "CSS distribution"},
        {"path": "dist/asset.min.js", "label": "JS distribution"}
      ]
    }],
  ]
}
```

---

I can also recommend using an alternative to semantic-release
called [atomic-release](https://github.com/abstracter-io/atomic-release).
It's an SDK with a strategy to release NPM packages (kind of like semantic-release). Check it out [GithubNpmPackageStrategy](https://github.com/abstracter-io/atomic-release/blob/main/docs/strategies/github-npm-package-strategy.md)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of atomic-release.

Comment: do you know how to upload the whole dist folder? I tried `dist`, `dist/`, `dist/*` and `dist/**` but still uploads every single file ...

Comment: So based on https://github.com/semantic-release/github#assets I tried https://pastebin.com/FhSQHKkU

Comment: Their docs state "If a directory is configured, all the files under this directory and its children will be included."

If that is not the case, you can open an issue.

Comment: moved it to another question first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872861/how-to-publish-a-whole-directory-using-github-actions-with-the-semantic-release