# How to publish a whole directory using Github Actions with the semantic-release Github plugin?

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, semantic-release

I want to publish a whole directory (the build directory) on a Github release using semantic-release but unfortunately it releases each build file as a single asset.

For reproduction:

- I'm using the Vue CLI to generate a project `vue create foo`
- Install semantic-release as a dev dependency `npm install --save-dev semantic-release`
- Install the Github plugin for semantic-release `npm install @semantic-release/github -D`
- Create a `.releaserc.json` with the content

.

```
{
    "plugins":[
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      [
        "@semantic-release/github",
        {
          "assets":[
            {
              "path":"dist",
              "label":"foo-${nextRelease.gitTag}"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

- Inside the *package.json* set the `version` key to `0.0.0-development`
- Create a *.github/workflows* directory with the workflow *ci.yml*

.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: npx semantic-release --branches main
```

- Commit and push it with `feat: pushed`

The release seems to be fine but unfortunately it didn't publish the *dist* directory as a single asset.

[image]

It simply published each file inside *dist* as a single

[image]

Adding the step

```
  - name: Log
    run: ls
```

shows that the *dist* directory exists

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible. So I have to add this step after building the app

```
  - name: ZIP build
    run: zip -r dist.zip dist
```

and set the assets config to

```
        {
          "path":"dist.zip",
          "label":"foo-${nextRelease.gitTag}.zip"
        }
```

Comment: this forces you to build the app on each commit even it doesn't generate a release, instead, you need to build the app inside the releasing process.